# How do you go about applying a Path's discount bonus to character progression/creation?

Tags: character-creation, shadowrun-sr5, character-advancement

> The Beast’s Way
>
> COST:20 KARMA
>
> PREREQUISITES:Adept
>
> RATING:NONE
>
> SOURCE:SR5:SG
>
> Adepts who follow this path are under the guidance of an animal mentor
> spirit, which they refer to as their totem, similar to some shamans.
> Through the emulation of their totem, these adepts seek to improve
> themselves, and like followers of the Spiritual Way, they’re
> considered to be more spiritual than the average adept. As such, they
> receive all the bonuses and drawbacks associated with their personal
> totem.
>
> Because of their unique outlook, followers of the Beast’s Way have an
> above-average rapport with nature and gain a +1 situational bonus to
> all Animal Handling Tests; however, if the adept’s totem is a
> predatory one, this bonus does not apply against animals that totem
> would normally consider prey. When dealing with the same animal as
> their totem, the adept gains an automatic +4 for any Animal Handling
> Tests involving them.
>
> ***Followers of the Beast’s Way may choose from the following skills for
> their discount bonus: Animal Empathy, Astral Perception, Berserk,
> Combat Sense, Elemental Strike, Enhanced Perception, Killing Hands,
> Magic Sense, Mystic Armor, Motion Sense, and Traceless Walk. In
> addition, Beast’s Way adepts are able to choose one power other power
> for the discount.***

The emphasized text leaves me a bit confused as it does not state what kind of discount is to be applied. In what way do these skills get a discount bonus? I have not been able to find how to handle this for character creation nor post creation.

Also, the final sentence reads really weird...

> In addition, Beast’s Way adepts are able to choose one power other power for the discount.

Comment: Iirc there's a description prior to the list of ways (the one listing the costs). Currentls don't have the *Street Grimoire* available to look it up though...

Answer (score 1):

When an adept chooses a way, they receive a discount on choosing specific adept powers based on the flavor of the way. The list you've bolded are all the choices of adept powers that you can purchase for a discount. The specific rules are listed on page 176 of Street Grimoire:

> For every 2 points in an adept’s Magic Rating, that adept may reduce the cost of one level of one power from that Way’s list by half ... The adept then can use the saved Power Points to buy a new power or new levels in an existing power at full cost. If an adept follows a Way and increases his Magic Rating through Initiation, he may use this discount every time he adds two points to his Magic Rating.

So, let's say you have a 6 in your magic attribute. This means you can take 3 (6 / 2) adept powers that are listed in your way (for Beast, that would be the list you mentioned in bold) for half of their regular PP cost.

The final sentence allows you to take any other power not listed for a discount. [This has been removed.](https://www.shadowruntabletop.com/wp-content/uploads/Downloads/E-CAT27003E_SG-Errata.pdf) I like to think it was removed because getting Improved Reflexes 3 (SR5 page 310) for only 1.75 PP is just dumb.

> P. 177, THE BEAST’S WAY POWER LIST CHANGE
>
> The last sentence, stating that Beast’s Way adepts can choose one additional power, should be removed.

Comment: What about when I raise my magic attribute beyond 6, and does this retroactively apply to already purchased powers before the Way was adopted and/or magic attribute was raised above 6.

Comment: You cannot apply them to powers you have already purchased.

"The adept then can use the saved Power Points to buy a new power or new levels in an existing power at full cost. If an adept follows a Way and increases his Magic Rating through Initiation, he may use this discount every time he adds two points to his Magic Rating." SG 176. I will add this to the answer.

Comment: can you provide the source stating it cant be used retroactively on say mystic armor 5, i am getting other people saying it does. since gaining this Way does not grant new powers or power points, how does picking mystic power 5 not give 2.5 points to 'The adept then can use the saved Power Points to buy a new power or new levels in an existing power at full cost.'

Comment: the quote you're referencing is specific to the adept gaining a higher magic rating via initiation. are you referring to a situation where an adept has already been running and wants to pick up a way quality after character creation?

Comment: yes, that is my specific scenario

Comment: at the end of that same paragraph on SG 176 "Players can amend previously created characters and retroactively purchase a Way. This is per the gamemaster’s discretion. See p. 103, SR5, for more information about purchasing and paying off qualities." So the way would cost you the regular karma amount (not double) since it's retroactive, and you would be able to apply the discounts to already acquired powers (all at GM discretion)

Comment: Cool thanks, but you said something that now confuses me and might be a good "post and answer yourself" question... what do you mean by 'cost regular and not double karma' does buying qualities after creation cost half the listed karma price?

Comment: SR 106 "The cost for purchasing a Positive quality during game play is the listed Karma cost x 2." Karma costs listed are only for character creation.